# autoconf check lib with many header files

Tags: c++, autoconf

So I understand that for a library like math, I can check for a function like floor with `AC_CHECK_LIB([m], [floor])` and if it exist autoconf will add `-lm` to the linking stage.

My problem is I have a compiled library with many header files so I am not sure what to do in that case. Say I have a lib called `foo` so I want to add `-lfoo` to the linking stage, I would check for a function called bar like this `AC_CHECK_LIB([foo], [bar])`, but that didn't work. Let's say bar is found in a header file called `abc.hpp` and has a namespace `foo`, how would I form my macro? I have also tried `AC_CHECK_LIB([foo], [foo::bar])` but that didn't work.

Comment: Consider using `AC_LINK_IFELSE` with the headers and libraries, and a small program body to test the contents of those headers / libraries.

Comment: Thanks lets say I do this `AC_LINK_IFELSE([AC_CHECK_HEADER([foo/abc.hpp], [add -lfoo], [AC_MSG_ERROR([need lib foo]) ])` . What macro can I use in the first part to add -lfoo at the end?

Comment: IIRC `AC_CHECK_LIB` just defines some symbol of that name and verifies that linking finds that symbol. However, the symbol for a C++ function `bar` is definitively not called `bar` due to name mangling, which requires proper definition of the function. `AC_LINK_IFELSE` as mentioned by @BrettHale will give you the proper definition. And of course, for non-C checks like C++ checks do not forget the proper `AC_LANG`/`AC_LANG_PUSH`/`AC_LANG_POP`.